# How to access custom environment variables in an aws batch job

Tags: aws-batch

I'm setting an environment variable in my aws batch job like so.

```
BatchJobDef:
    Type: 'AWS::Batch::JobDefinition'
    Properties:
      Type: container
      JobDefinitionName:  xxxxxxxxxx
      ContainerProperties:       
        Environment:
          - Name: 'PROC_ENV'
            Value: 'dev'
```

When I look at my job definition I can see it listed in *Environment variables configuration*


Then I'm trying to access it in my job's python code like this:

```
env = os.environ['PROC_ENV']
```

but there is no PROC_ENV variable set, getting the following error when I go to run my job:

```
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PROC_ENV'
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Am I accessing this environment variable the correct way?

Comment: So I tried running the job again 30min later and it ran just fine, Environment variable was set. I don't have a good explanation.  Perhaps there is a lag between when the job definition is updated to when a job's containers is deployed with this environment variable.